# Remove/Replace/Combine tag generated from parent List<> object in XStream

Tags: java, serialization, xml-serialization, xstream

I'm using XStream to convert java objects to their XML counterparts.

One such object contains a `List<Window> windows` variable, which when generated displays:

```
<windows>
    <Window>
                  <WindowType>Monthly</WindowType>
                  <WindowBegin>
                    <Month>null</Month>
                    <Day>null</Day>
                  </WindowBegin>
                  <WindowEnd>
                    <Month>null</Month>
                    <Day>null</Day>
                  </WindowEnd>
    </Window>
    <Window>
    ....
    </Window>
</windows>
```

I would like to know if it's possible to prevent the List<> parent tag from being generated, like so:

```
        <Window>
                      <WindowType>Monthly</WindowType>
                      <WindowBegin>
                        <Month>null</Month>
                        <Day>null</Day>
                      </WindowBegin>
                      <WindowEnd>
                        <Month>null</Month>
                        <Day>null</Day>
                      </WindowEnd>
        </Window>
        <Window>
        ....
        </Window>
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754807/remove-xml-tag-during-xstream-parsing) uses string.replace, but this will leave gaps in the xml if this list is within another object that need to be cleaned. Speed is of top priority for this, so I was looking for an approach from  within XStream itself if possible.

Thanks

Comment: If you remove the `<windows></windows>` tags the result won't be deserializable via XStream.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: To match a given schema. The schema has multiple Window(s), so I have them stored as a List<> under it's parent object. I was hoping there was a work around for this...

Comment: Sorry if the question's wording confused you @JimGarrison, I wasn't too sure of the solution myself, glad I found that site. Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that I didn't word the question correctly, but the solution I found (through XStream) doesn't exactly remove the tag, but uses implicit naming to combine the parent tag with its children. 
Thanks to [@Blaise Doughan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan) excellent [tutorials](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html) for this.

Ex)

List windows; 
Will serialize to:

```
<windows>
    <Window>
                  <WindowType>Monthly</WindowType>
                  <WindowBegin>
                    <Month>null</Month>
                    <Day>null</Day>
                  </WindowBegin>
                  <WindowEnd>
                    <Month>null</Month>
                    <Day>null</Day>
                  </WindowEnd>
    </Window>
    <Window>
    ....
    </Window>
</windows>
```

But adding:

```
@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="Window")
List<Window> windows;
```

will serialize to:

```
        <Window>
                      <WindowType>Monthly</WindowType>
                      <WindowBegin>
                        <Month>null</Month>
                        <Day>null</Day>
                      </WindowBegin>
                      <WindowEnd>
                        <Month>null</Month>
                        <Day>null</Day>
                      </WindowEnd>
        </Window>
        <Window>
        ....
        </Window>
```